# Add an action based on custom post meta field

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, post-meta

I need to add every single post as a custom hook, in every post I have tow field, `mycode` will be code content and need to hook it to custom action, this custom action Ill get it from `myhook_before_content` post meta.

How can I do this? my full code:

```
 <?php
     function codes() {
        $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'codes',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            // 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            $post_id = get_the_ID(); // successfully returned code id
            $hook_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'myhook_before_content', true );
            $code_field = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycode', true );
            add_action( $hook_field , function() {
                echo get_the_ID(); // It will return current post id not code id
                echo $code_field; // return nothing
            });
            
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    }
add_action( 'init', 'codes');
```

Comment: Use the `use` keyword to access the local variable - `function() use ( $code_field ) {` ..

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to let users write JS/HTML in a CPT then output it on a WP hook? Also note that your hook doesn't return anything, so if it's a filter it will break the filter

Comment: Yes @TomJNowell , my hook is action.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ, `$code_field` now echo the correct code, but `$hook_field` always return first post meta that not related to `$code_field`.

Comment: You would use it by reference, so that it gets the new value in your next loop: `&$code_field` - but the closure itself shouldn't modify the variable - and I'm just letting you know how can you access the local variable from inside a closure.

Comment: @SallyCJ , `$code_field` is ok, how I can use & with `$hook_field`? `add_action( $hook_field , function() use ( $code_field ) { echo $code_field; });`

Comment: Use `use ( &$code_field )`. See *Example #3 Inheriting variables from the parent scope* in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). But actually, why don't you use a named function (e.g. `my_hook_callback`) and then in that function, do something like `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mycode', true );`?

Comment: Thanks, because `get_the_ID()` returned the current post id not code id

Comment: @techno behind the scenes, actions and filters are the same thing. Also, `get_the_ID` will return the current post at the time the function is executed, not the post ID of the `code` post in the loop, is this intentional?

Comment: No @TomJNowell, I need to get `code` post ID so I can get all codes with it's actions positions.

Comment: then you need to do that and pass the post ID to the function, you cannot do that inside the function